# What happens to a GEE model when only a few cases have repeated values?

Tags: generalized-estimating-equations

I am working with data in which approximately 17% (20 out of 120) of cases come from bilateral subjects. Is it worth using GEE to account for the potential bias the dependence between subjects may create? Will GEE be stable with so few repeated measures?